# Create view in postgres sql with comments

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-view

I create a view in postgres sql with sql statement

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW  {ViewName} as 
Select
.....
```

I am asking is there any way to create comments for columns in the view.
After the view is created, it generates an error when a comment is added to a column :

> ERROR: "{ViewName}" is not a table, composite type, or foreign table.

Comment: please share the full statement, or at least show example of comments youwant

Comment: What is the SQL statement that generates that error?

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW  {ViewName} as 
Select
column1,
column2,
....

Comment: That can't be the real statement. (`{ViewName}` is an invalid identifier to begin with)

Comment: CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW  {ViewName} as 
Select
column1,
column2,
....

And I want columns with comments . 
Error is generated when I manually try to set a comment after clicking column properties.
I want when someone is looking at the view to see a comments for each columns as it is a regular table.Every table in out database consist of columns with comments and I want to preserve this approach.

Comment: {ViewName} is just the name of my view

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To define a comment on a column (or a view) use [`comment on`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-comment.html):

```
create view some_view
as
select x as col1, y as col2, z as col3
from some_table;
```

Then:

```
comment on view some_view is 'Some View';
comment on column some_view.col1 is 'Originally column X';
```

Comment: OK I manage to add comment on the view itself but I get an error
ERROR:  cross-database references are not implemented: "some_view.col1"

Comment: It's working I just misspell my column name , sorry. Thanks @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 0):

Use a dummy select statement.

```
select 'general information for the use of the comments' as c1;
```

It's clunky but the only way I can find to embed comments.
For larger items, I create a commentary in a header.

```
with query_header as (
    select 'purpose - statement' as c1,
    select 'revision - revised 16 Oct 2019 by WDH' as c2
    select 'owner - contact details' as c3
    select 'lines 234-312 to declutter orders with no valid partnmber' as c4
    select 'join on itemtable changed to left join 23July2018 by WDH' as c5
)
```